# How to access SURF's KeyPoints' characteristic scales and dominant orientations in python?

Tags: python, opencv, sift, surf

I'm reading a paper titled 'Local Geometric Consistency Constraint for Image Retrieval'. The author introduces a method to make the matched SFIT points are right using local geometric consistency. This method requires points' characteristic scales and dominant orientation.

In python, I use opencv to extract SURF keypoints. How could I get points' characteristic scales and dominant orientation?

Comment: After extracting the Keypoints, you can access the properties of the array returned by `detectAndCompute`

Comment: the method detectAndCompute returns kp and des. des is an array of 128 dimensions vector. kp contains angle, size, pt, response, size, octave and class_id. Is 'angle' the dominant orientaion? And what corresponds to characteristic scale?

Comment: Try reading the research paper on SURF, it'll answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Creat SURF feature extractor with

```
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
kpu, desu = surf.detectAndCompute(image, None)
```

keypoints are stored in kpu, now you can do something like:

```
for i in range(len(kpu)):
     point = kpu[i].pt
     print("your point here", point)
```